# Display average quantity of product in warehouses using record type pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to display a list of product names where the ID is between 100-105, with the average quantity in all warehouses, and the name of the warehouse that has the most product quantity (for each product). The only problem is that the average (f_avg) is not working, instead, f_avg is displaying the greatest quantity of the product.

The output example is:

1. Kingston HyperX Predator average product: 173 mostly found in San Francisco
2. Intel Xeon E5-2687W V4 average product: 90 mostly found in Toronto
3. EVGA 12G-P4-3992-KR average product: 178 mostly found in San Francisco

This is my code, anyone know what's wrong with the average and i also got an error:

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression ORA-06512: at line 3

ORA-06512: at line 14

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

It will be much better if you don't change the structure of the code, but the most important thing is, i need to use record type

```
 DECLARE
 CURSOR cur_emp_detail IS
   SELECT pproduct_name, avg_quantity, (SELECT w.warehouse_name FROM warehouses w WHERE w.warehouse_id = (SELECT i.warehouse_id FROM inventories i join products p on p.product_id = i.product_id HAVING i.quantity = MAX (i.quantity))) as ware
    FROM (SELECT p.product_name as pproduct_name, AVG (i.quantity) AS avg_quantity
                       FROM products p JOIN inventories i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
                      WHERE (p.product_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105)
                   GROUP BY p.product_name);
 TYPE type_record_type IS RECORD (
   emp_f_name products.product_name%TYPE,
   emp_avg inventories.quantity%type,
   emp_wh warehouses.warehouse_name%type);
 emp_rec_type type_record_type;
     BEGIN
     OPEN cur_emp_detail;
     LOOP
         FETCH cur_emp_detail INTO emp_rec_type;
         EXIT WHEN cur_emp_detail%NOTFOUND;
         dbms_output.Put_line(emp_rec_type.emp_f_name||' average product: '||emp_rec_type.emp_avg||' mostly found in '||emp_rec_type.emp_wh);
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE cur_emp_detail;
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `BULK COLLECT` is much more efficient then looping through a cursor.  This reduces the amount of context switches and still allows you to reference each row as a record type.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE product_rec IS RECORD
    (
        emp_f_name    products.product_name%TYPE,
        emp_avg       inventories.quantity%TYPE,
        emp_wh        warehouses.warehouse_name%TYPE
    );

    TYPE product_t IS TABLE OF product_rec;

    l_products   product_t;
BEGIN
    SELECT product_name, avg_quantity, warehouse_name
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_products
      FROM (SELECT p.product_name,
                   AVG (i.quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id)                              AS avg_quantity,
                   w.warehouse_name,
                   ROW_NUMBER ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_NAME ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC, WAREHOUSE_NAME)    warehouse_order
              FROM products  p
                   JOIN inventories i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
                   JOIN warehouses w ON i.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id
             WHERE (p.product_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105))
     WHERE warehouse_order = 1;

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_products.COUNT
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line (
               l_products (i).emp_f_name
            || ' average product: '
            || l_products (i).emp_avg
            || ' mostly found in '
            || l_products (i).emp_wh);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that bulk collect consumes much more memory and depending on the amount of data you can run into errors ORA-04030 or ORA-04031. You might consider in this case to use the clause `LIMIT` for the `BULK COLLECT INTO`

Comment: `BULK COLLECT` increase the complexity and if the data set you are expecting is not big then normal loop is always better.

Comment: It could, but based on the original query, information for only ~5 products are being selected so < 10 rows shouldn't consume that much memory.

Comment: Despite adding of `GROUP BY i.warehouse_id` in the subquery it still fails with `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` -  `HAVING i.quantity = MAX (i.quantity)` is not allowed because `i.quantity` is not a `GROUP BY` column. Simple test yourself.

Comment: Thanks @marmite. I updated the query to use something similar to yours.

Comment: I sort of agree and disagree with what @Sujitmohanty30 said: yes, an implicit cursor loop is simpler to look at perhaps than a BULK COLLECT setup, but always better?  If "better" here is used to measure context switches then that sort of loop is certainly not.  I think the point was that substantially increasing code complexity for what might amount to a tiny performance gain may not a good idea, but there are edge cases for everything so we should avoid blanket statements like "always better".

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a structured approach using subqueries as follow

**1) subquery to produce detail data: product, warehouse and quantity**

Note that I assume the table `inventories` has a primary key `product_id, warehouse_id`, if not you must additionaly aggregate the quantity with grouping by `product_id, warehouse_id`

```
SELECT p.product_name, w.warehouse_name, i.quantity 
 FROM products p 
 JOIN inventories i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouses w ON w.warehouse_id =  i.warehouse_id
 WHERE (p.product_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105);
 
PRODUCT_ WAREHOUSE_NAM   QUANTITY
-------- ------------- ----------
Kingston San Francisco        173
EVGA     Toronto              178
Intel    Toronto               70
Intel    Toronto               90
Kingston Toronto              173
```

**2) calculate the AVG quantity and the warehouse rank** - using analytic functions

```
with prd as (
 SELECT p.product_name, w.warehouse_name, i.quantity 
 FROM products p 
 JOIN inventories i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouses w ON w.warehouse_id =  i.warehouse_id
 WHERE (p.product_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105)
),
prd2 as (
select 
  PRODUCT_NAME, WAREHOUSE_NAME, QUANTITY,
  avg(QUANTITY) over (partition by PRODUCT_NAME) avg_quantity,
  row_number() over (partition by PRODUCT_NAME order by QUANTITY desc, WAREHOUSE_NAME) warehouse_order
from prd)
select * from prd2;

PRODUCT_ WAREHOUSE_NAM   QUANTITY AVG_QUANTITY WAREHOUSE_ORDER
-------- ------------- ---------- ------------ ---------------
EVGA     Toronto              178          178               1
Intel    Toronto               90           80               1
Intel    Toronto               70           80               2
Kingston San Francisco        173          173               1
Kingston Toronto              173          173               2
```

**3) get per product only the record with the top warehouse**

```
with prd as (
 SELECT p.product_name, w.warehouse_name, i.quantity 
 FROM products p 
 JOIN inventories i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouses w ON w.warehouse_id =  i.warehouse_id
 WHERE (p.product_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105)
),
prd2 as (
select 
  PRODUCT_NAME, WAREHOUSE_NAME, QUANTITY,
  avg(QUANTITY) over (partition by PRODUCT_NAME) avg_quantity,
  row_number() over (partition by PRODUCT_NAME order by QUANTITY desc, WAREHOUSE_NAME) warehouse_order
from prd)
select PRODUCT_NAME, WAREHOUSE_NAME, AVG_QUANTITY 
from prd2
where warehouse_order = 1; 

PRODUCT_ WAREHOUSE_NAM AVG_QUANTITY
-------- ------------- ------------
EVGA     Toronto                178
Intel    Toronto                 80
Kingston San Francisco          173
```

If you insist use the CURSOR and your record_type - the core logic is the the query above.

*Two notes:*

Using `MAX(quantity)` to get the top record is a *naive* approach, that badly fails if you have ties, i.e. the MAX equals to more than one record!
See my implementation where in case of ties is shown the warehouse with the lower name

```
 order by QUANTITY desc, WAREHOUSE_NAME
```

Grouping on `NAME`s is possible, but fails if you have more products with the same name - typically you group by `ID`s

**Sample data**

```
create table products as
select 100 product_id, 'Kingston' product_name from dual union all
select 101 product_id, 'Intel ' product_name from dual union all
select 102 product_id, 'EVGA  ' product_name from dual;

create table inventories as
select 100 product_id, 173 quantity, 1 warehouse_id from dual union all
select 100 product_id, 173 quantity, 2 warehouse_id from dual union all
select 101 product_id, 90 quantity, 2 warehouse_id from dual union all
select 101 product_id, 70 quantity, 2 warehouse_id from dual union all
select 102 product_id, 178 quantity, 2 warehouse_id from dual;

create table warehouses as
select 1 warehouse_id, 'San Francisco' warehouse_name from dual union all
select 2 warehouse_id, 'Toronto' warehouse_name from dual;
```